# replace sub tag from html file by something else

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like below:

```
string = "<sub>1</sub>"
```

I wanna change the tag sub to something like this:

```
 "<sub>1</sub>" ->  "-sub--1--sub-"
```

I've tried this:

```
string1 = re.sub('<sub.*>','-sub--',string)
string1 = re.sub('</sub>','--sub-',string)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
re.sub(r"<([^>]*)>([^<]*)<\/([^>]*)>", r"-\1--\2--\3-", string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used the greedy operator `.*`, where the non-greedy operator `.*?` would work better. Additionally, your second change overrides your first.
Try this:

```
string1 = re.sub('<sub.*?>','-sub--',string)
string1 = re.sub('</sub>','--sub-',string1)
```

However, you should probably [avoid using regex to parse XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la). Use an XML parser instead.